# how to make api request call on Application class on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I need to get a data from an endpoint at begin of my app. I don't know if this is the best practice or not. But I need get it before app's started.

I didnt a suggestion or solution on web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a class extend Application class and call request on oncreate function.

```
class YourApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // load data
    }
}
```

in mainfest application tag please add : android:name=".YourApplication"